# What to send an SMS using an ANDROIRD app on a tablet viaGoogle Messenger

Tags: android, smsmanager

Using Android 5.1 on Nexus tablet that doesn't have native SMS capabilities.

I am trying to use Google Messenger to send a SMS text from the tablet via an Android App without intervention.

Google Messenger is installed and I do get the Toast that the message has been sent.

However I don't get a text message to the phone I am trying to send to
AND 
the Test Text appears and stays stuck on the screen and the app doesn't go back its normal processing.

------------ Code I am using but I have replaced the phone number -----------

```
public void sendMessenger(String phoneNo, String message) {

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:5555555555"); 
    Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,uri);

    waIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.messaging", "com.google.android.apps.messaging.Main");

    waIntent.setType("text/plain");

    String text = "testing message";

    waIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.messaging");


    if (waIntent != null) {
        waIntent.putExtra("address", "5555555555");

        waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);

        waIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "HI");

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, text));

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Message Sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Google Messenger NOT Installed!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: If it doesn't have a SIM card and a cellular plan, you can't send an SMS.  You'd need to send it via a SMS gateway provider, which will likely charge you per message.

Comment: Well I can wechat and hangouts to send a message from this tablet manually so not sure why I couldn't do the same via Messenger programmatically

Comment: There's a difference between sending a message and sending an SMS.  A message uses the internet.  SMS is a specific protocol over the cellular network.